# "Anfang April", "Ab Anfang April", "Ab Anfang von April"

Tags: phrase, time, standard-german

I was reading this flyer that said:

> Anfang April werden ihnen die Fahrausweise nach Hause geschickt.

And it got me thinking... Is it gramatically correct to simply say `Anfang April`? It kinda feels like some prepositions are missing there. Like, I would say `Ab Anfang von April` or `Am Anfang des April` or something similar.

- Is this way correct?
- What are other correct ways to write such an expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. "Anfang April" is used for one time activity.  "Ab Anfang April" is correct too but it's used for regular activities -  "Ab Anfang April werde ich jede Woche ins Kino gehen".

Comment: I corrected the message, because I copied it wrong from the flyer. Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: What if I used "am Anfang April"? Would that be also for regular activities?

Comment: @Dbugger, "Am Anfang April..." ist einfach falsch. Es ginge aber "Am Anfang des Monats (April) ...".

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you mean to say: You can either say

> Anfang April werden....

Which means "we'll send out the tickets beginning of April" (like 1/04-5/04)

or

> Ab Anfang April werden...

saying "starting from beginning of April we will be sending out tickets" (But that process could last until November...) And in my opinion, the usage of "ab" has nothing to do whether the activity is regular or not.

Comment: My fault, I should have said "am", not "ab". I corrected the question.

Comment: In this case, don't change the "ab" to "am", but rather leave it out . "Am Anfang des April" is grammatically correct, but still sounds wrong to me - I would not use it. "Am Anfang April" is just wrong.

Comment: I understand the regular activity like this: They send not all tickets at once but send them out in different charges.